# Localization in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I'm trying to make my project Localized, using .resx files.

For me it does not work, for my colleague, who is working on the project too it works.

Some details about the code:
Startup.cs file

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            .
            .
            .
            // Localization

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Lang/");

            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();



            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("cs"),
                        //new CultureInfo("en")
                    };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "cs", uiCulture: "cs");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
            services.AddTransient<Messages>();
            // Localization end
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // Localization
            var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
            // Localization end

            .
            .
            .

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

My controller:

```
public class AccountController : BasicController
    {     
        private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
        private readonly IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher;
        private IStringLocalizer<Default> _localizer;


        public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher,
            IStringLocalizer<Default> LangDefault, IDataProtectionProvider provider) : base(signInManager,provider)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
            _localizer = LangDefault;
        }
```

My Login View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    Layout = "_LayoutLogin";
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["TitleLogin"];
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o7Q3.png)

for me it returns "TitleLogin" and the value "ResourceNotFound" is true.

For my colleague it returns correct value with the same code...

Could you please help me - what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know which resx file contains `TitleLogin`.For displaying correct localization data, it wroks when I modify `services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Lang/");` to

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Lang");
```

And then add a resx file named `Views.Account.Login.cs.resx` in `Lang` folder.

**Update 3/19/2020**

It turns out that in asp.net core 3.1, you need to place `Default.cs` out of Resources folder(your `Lang` folder here),see this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17733).

If class `Default.cs` and `Default.*.resx` in same folder, the namespace will be error in compiled dll xxx.lang.dll.

So, the solution is

1.Delete original `Default.cs`  and create a new one under the project directly:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Default
    {
    }
}
```

2.Add `Default.cs.resx` in the `Lang` folder

3._ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using MyApp
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Default> LangDefault
```

Comment: Many thanks for advice. This works, but I would like to have only few resx files (because a lot of messages for each view are common). TitleLogin is contained in Default.cs.resx, so I wanted to use LangDefault["TitleLogin"], but the found value is null...

Comment: I just want to add, that in ViewImports I have @inject IStringLocalizer<Default> LangDefault... And when I look in LangDefault ->Non-Public members ->_localizer -> Non-Public members ->_missingManifestCache, there I can find my TitleLogin, but value is null...

Comment: @Lukas I find it is a breaking change and please check my edited answer.