# my web app gets translation from the french resource, idk why

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-3.0

I started some weeks ago to develop a web application using asp.net core 3.0, now I got to the phase where I must develop the localization service, to simplify my code, I will only write the new "parts" so here they are:
startup.cs:
the ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
                services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                   .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                   .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
                   .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
                services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                        {
                            new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                        };
    
                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en-US");
                    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });
                services.AddTransient<SharedResources>();
```

the `SharedResources.cs` is located in the app root
the `Configure` method

```
var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

_ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Backoffice.SharedResources> LangDefault
@addTagHelper *, Localisation
```

a View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@model some-model
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">@Localizer["Sede"]</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">@Localizer["FirstName"]</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my app only gets the french translation from `Views.[SomeController].[SomeAction].fr.resx`, I couldn't find how to make a select list to change the language, what I find are either for API apps or an old .net core, I found [this guide that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722888/localization-in-asp-net-core-3-0), but it missed some points, can you provide an adapted guide or some help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo worked:

/Shared/Partial:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions
@*@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Partial";
    }

    <h1>Partial</h1>*@

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label> 
        <select name="culture"
                                                                                                               onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                                                                                               asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

_layout.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
 <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
        <div>
            @Localizer["Hello"]
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("Partial")
        </div>
    </div>
```

Startup.cs:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(
                LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                        new CultureInfo("de-DE")
                    };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

            });
```

Configure:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "fr-FR", "de-DE" };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
```

HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
            );

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

Resources:

[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: think you for the reply, you have no idea how much pages I visited, they are either for `.net core 2.2` (and I am with `.net core 3.0`, it could work but there are some problems like: it is not allowed to make a class in the `Resources` folder in .net core 3.0 whereas you must make one in `.net core 2.2`, plus there's no complete walkthrough and I am, let's say, I started developing full-time a few weeks ago) or they are for `Web API` which is not my project (like in the official Microsoft documentations) anyway, I don't have a Partial Razor Page in my `Shared`folder, do I have to create it?

Comment: here's what I have in the `Shared` folder [link](https://ibb.co/dPxwnwv)

Comment: If you don't want to create the partial view,you can also not create it,and put the code of it to any other page you need.I use it in the sample is because you can use `@await Html.PartialAsync("Partial")` to reuse the code in other pages.

Comment: just an information, in french hello=="Bonjour" not "Hola" but you could be confusing French with Spanish, or you could be an online gamer (French people say Hola a lot in online games like WoW)

Comment: BTW for me, I stopped using chrome for a long time but since this application is intended to run for many clients, do you have a solution why the cookie doesn't persist on chrome? (for the localization I mean), I tested at first with Opera, it works, but in chrome it doesn't until I changed the return of the `SetLanguage` method from  `return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);` to `return LocalRedirect(returnUrl+"?culture="+culture+"&handler=SetCulture");`but the cookie still doesn't persist, at least the translation works

Comment: one other thing: is there a solution for a live update (i.e when I add the translation in the .resx file, it applies to the page without rerunning the application)?